# Ace editor marker update

Tags: ace-editor

When I add error annotations to the editor, their position gets automatically updated when new lines are added. But how can I achieve the same for Markers?

The only solution I could think of would be to listen to changes, store them, and apply all deltas to all markers.. This doesn't seem to be very efficient..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently adding change listener is the only way. And Cloud9 does the same (see https://github.com/c9/core/blob/4ee99bd/plugins/c9.ide.language.core/marker.js#L201)

Of course this isn't very efficient if you are going to add many markers, and having some kind of tree would be much better, but renderer code itself [simply iterates](https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/blob/54e022fab25ae40f839e9df13ac5db75d79f98f7/lib/ace/layer/marker.js#L67) over all markers, and it will become bottleneck before applying all deltas to all markers becomes slow, so if you need to display large amount of markers, you should open an issue on ace site asking for that feature, which seems to be the kind of feature that should be built in, instead of being reimplemented by everyone.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in that direction, that looks like what I am look for. It also appears that ext.language does a lot more stuff that could be really useful for me. Is there any documentation on how to get started with it?

Comment: Your link is broken.

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered this problem too, and finally found a gorgeous demo to resolve this question: [Ace Editor Marker Popovers](https://codepen.io/oatssss/pen/oYxJQV?editors=0010)

Here is the key code to resolve the problem:

```
var range = new Range(startRow, startColumn, endRow, endColumn);
var session = editor.getSession();

range.start = session.doc.createAnchor(range.start);
range.end = session.doc.createAnchor(range.end);

var id = session.addMarker(range, 'your_marker_class_name');
```